# Convert wav to mp3 with avconv using pipes

Tags: php, pipe, avconv

I'm trying to convert a .wav file to an .mp3 using avconv/"ffmpeg" from Libav with pipes for stdin and stdout, however, my output .mp3 results in 0 bytes.

This is what I currently do:

```
$desc = array(
  0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
  1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
);

$cmd = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i pipe:0 -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 5 pipe:1";

$p = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);

fwrite($pipes[0], $wav); // $wav contains the wav file data.
fclose($pipes[0]);

$mp3 = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

// At this point doing strlen($mp3) returns 0

proc_close($p);
```

How can I convert a .wav file to .mp3 with ffmpeg using piped input and output?

PS: As a sanity test running the following command from the command line results in a converted .mp3:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i test.wav -acodec libmp3lame -q:a 5 test.mp3
```

**UPDATE**

After applying LordNeckbeard's suggestion, the ffmpeg command seem to hang. I also enabled the ffmpeg output to get some feedback and it now seems to indeed be waiting. Not sure why, the input .wav has a fixed duration...

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1+fdkaac, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr 10 2015 23:18:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[wav @ 0x150e460] max_analyze_duration reached
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'pipe:0':
  Duration: 00:00:15.04, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'pipe:1':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, mono, s16p
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
```

Comment: Try adding `-f mp3` as an output option.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks. That seem like a good suggestion. I have added an update to my question with some more info.

Comment: Ohh...`avconv`. I know nothing of that. Thought you were using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Both `avconv` and `ffmpeg` are pretty much the same. `avconv` is basically the Ubuntu compiled version of `ffmpeg`. Same tool, different name for the binary.

Comment: It is not the same tool: `avconv` is from Libav, a fork of FFmpeg, although I can see why you assume they are only different in name only since Libav had their own fake "`ffmpeg`" for some time. Additionally, `avconv` is missing many features that are present in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: That's what I mean with "pretty much the same". I've used avconv as a substitute for ffmpeg for a long time now and even though there might be differences, so far I haven't had any issues. So, for the sake of the question, they're pretty much the same. What I'm trying to do works fine from the command line so it's safe to say it's not an avconv vs ffmpeg issue.

Comment: In general, there are too many variables to ever assume that it is safe to say that anything is "not an `avconv` vs `ffmpeg` issue". For example, when requesting help from the official FFmpeg support resources you're expected to test the a current version because development is so active, and therefore old versions often don't work where a recent one does. Also, I don't provide answers for tools that I do not use since I prefer not to rely only on guesswork.

Comment: Let's not turn this into a avconv vs ffmpeg discussion. this is not an official ffmpeg support forum. The problem doesn't seem to lie with avconv/ffmpeg, it's more likely to be a PHP issue. I appreciate your input but this isn't helping. Thanks.